# Not able to connect to MSSQL server database using the node js I am using the package mssql , version is "mssql": "^6.2.0"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database-connection

I am trying to connect to mssql server from node js . I am using "mssql" package to connect .

- Able to connect if the version of  package is  "mssql": "^4.2.2"
- Not able to connect to database if the version is "mssql": "^6.2.0" .
  I want to update the drivers to 6.2.0 :

const sql = require("msnodesqlv8");

```
const connectionString = "server=name;Database=DBname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}";
const query = "SELECT TOP (1000) [sid] FROM [DBname].[dbo].[tablename]";

x = sql.open(connectionString, function (err, con) {
if (err)
console.log("error ", err);

})
```

when I try to execute the code : node index.js
there is no output , just it stops abruptly and return to the command prompt

Comment: Are you using `mssql` or `msnodesqlv8`? If you're trying to use `mssql@6.2.0` in your package.config file then shouldn't the setup be more mssql-like, e.g.: `const sql = require("mssql"); const connectionString = "mssql://name/DBName";`? ref: [node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Comment: I am using both packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with Node version.
changed the node version from 10.2.1 to 10.15.1 , then node was able to connect to Database .
I guess Node 10.2.1 does not work with package .